# Change logo size in opencart2 for responsive view

Tags: responsive-design, header, opencart

I tried editing the img-responsive max-width to 50% in bootstrap.min.css the logo size reduces to 50% but the slider image also reduces to 50% I want only the logo(responsive) to be 50%

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class to the logo image in the header.tpl.
Then in stylesheet.css make a new entry with .newstyle { max-width:50%; }

Comment: Sorry but I am very new at coding, will you please share the code of it! How to add a class in header.tpl and also how to make a new entryin stylesheet.css Please help me!

Comment: I followed your steps sir, but my question was for the responsive view sir...the logo size is getting reduced to 50% also for the non-responsive view! Please help